# fetch data from SQL and populate dynamicaly on html

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

i am working on simple retail management web app.i have sale page which have a input field which gets data from a bar code scanner.here is sample code of it

html code

```
<div id = "sale-form" class="form-group">
<label>PRODUCT CODE</label>
<input type="text" id ="get-code"><span   class="errors" id="get-code- error"></span>
</div>
<script>
       $(document).ready(function(){
         $('#get-code').focus();
          })                 
</script>

<div id="bill">

</div>
```

j query

```
$('#get-code').bind('change paste ',function(){
    var vall = $(this).val();
    if(vall == ""){
     $('#get-code-error').text("NO PRODUCT CODE ENTERED");
    }
    else{
    //run some script to fetch data and add row to $('#bill') dynamically;   
    }

})
```

i need help in the script which fetches data from SQL based on product code
adds a editable row to the div with id bill every time when new data is typed in input.i have tried with html table but unable to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost did it: you have the change and paste event and it should work.
In the else statement, where you have the comment just make an ajax request to the web server to get the data and on the success parse the response and display it in the div. Documentation of the ajax method of jquery can be found here: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

If the problem is adding the row in the div: just use the append method of jquery.